# How to add values in a loop to an array in asp classic?

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

In a loop I send a request to a page and in the 200 status callback I need to create an array with the response that I get back in the callback.

```
photoarray=array(photoarray)

    For Each x In imagearray
       --sending request to a page here----
       If objXmlHttp.Status = 200 Then

            photoId=oJSON.data("id")
            --I need to add all the photoIds that I get here into the photoarray--
                
       end if
    Next

response.write "All ids in this array "&photoarray
```

So how do I push or add values to the photoarray?

In the end I need to create a string like this with the photoIds I get in the loop.

```
media_id="{media_id:12345,media_id:45678,media_id:98765}"
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `photoarray=array(photoarray)` <-- What is this for?

Answer (score 1):

To retain your existing code, I might suggest appending all the response id's into a single string separated by a unique char (eg, `|`), then use the `Split()` function to easily convert the string into an array after your loop.

For example:

```
Dim photoId : photoId = ""
For Each x In imagearray
    If objXmlHttp.Status = 200 Then
        
        If Len(photoId) = 0 Then
            photoId = oJSON.data("id")
        Else
            photoId = photoId & "|" & oJSON.data("id")
        End If
        
    End If
Next

Dim photoarray : photoarray = Split(photoId, "|")
Response.Write "All ids in this array " & Join(photoarray, ",")
```

Comment: to format Join() as json: `media_id = "{media_id:" & Join(photoarray,",media_id:") & "}"`